# ES2015 grandchild inheritence bypass chain with Babel transpiler

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm using ES2015 Babel transpiler.

I've run into something really weird. The actual classes are complex. So I'll use an example which I didn't actually run. It's a timing issue I don't know if I can exactly replicate it with the following code, but the idea is like this:

```js
class A {
  static instance() {
    if (!A._instance) {
       A._instance = new A();
    }
    return A._instance;
  }

  foo() {
    console.log('A')
  }
}

class B extends A {
  static instance() {
    if (!B._instance) {
       B._instance = new B();
    }
    return A._instance;
  }

  foo() {
    console.log('B')
    super.foo();
  }
}

class C extends B {
  static instance() {
    if (!C._instance) {
       C._instance = new C();
    }
    return C._instance;
  }

  foo() {
    console.log('C')
    super.foo();
  }
}

// Somewhere else
class User {
  static bar() {
    C.instance().foo(); // Sometimes, this calls B.foo() directly, C.foo() is bypassed!
  }
}

// create A._instance first
A.instance().foo();

// now C will inherint _instance from B which inherits is from A.
User.bar()
```

I'm running ES6 transpiler with Gulp in a vanilla Cordova project. But when I tried to run it in desktop Chrome the same thing happens.

Sometimes `C.instance().foo()` doesn't actually calls the `foo` defined in C, but calls `B.instance().foo()`. By "sometimes", I mean I can replicate it 100% in Chrome when I load the login page, and login as usual. But I never can replicate it, if the `Remember me` options of the app is checked, and the user login directly to the main page. It seems like it's a timing issue. But I have no idea  exactly what it is. Any clues?

**EDIT 1:**
Code files are included into the project by using plain old embedded script tags individually inside index.html.

Comment: I've converted your code to runnable example. Transpilation is done by babel. It doesn't show the error described. I do recommend you to create a minimal example that demonstrate the issue and post transpiled code.

Comment: I've added possible scenario that probably demonstrates the issue you have described. :) If not just revert my changes back :)

Comment: Singletons are broken. Singletons with inheritance are even more broken. Don't try to do this at all.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Wow, many thanks! I didn't know I can do this.

Comment: @Bergi By broken to you mean it's a broken design? Or do you mean it's broken in the language? A lot of times I don't know what else to use though.

Comment: @huggie A broken design. Don't use a `class` for things where you only need a single instance, use an object literal to make the module. (Why they would need to inherit from each other is not clear).

Comment: The idea of the class is a REST data mapper as described from Martin Fowler [https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html](DataMapper). As for inheritance I just use it for different REST end points. The in-house REST API is designed with inconsistencies and sometimes I need specialized handling, and that's what inheritance is for. Some argues that singletons is global and is bad. I am thinking of a class with only static methods. But I think it's more convenient to store ivars. I don't know the merit of class singleton vs object literal. Seems like the same to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the problem is the following.

If you call parent class `instance` method first your child class will have `_instance` property as well due to inheritance. You need to check if you child class has own property named `_instance`.

```js
class A {
  /**
   * OOP all the way. Let's define static method that 
   * checks for own property `_instance`
   */
  static hasOwnInstance() {
    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this, '_instance')
  }
  static instance() {
    // rewrite to use this instead of class name
    if (!this.hasOwnInstance()) { // now we check only own properties
       this._instance = new this();
    }
    return this._instance;
  }

  foo() {
    console.log('A')
  }
}

class B extends A {
  /* Now safe to simply inherit implementation from A
  static instance() {
    if (!B.hasOwnInstance()) {  // now we check only own properties
       B._instance = new B();
    }
    return B._instance;
  } */

  foo() {
    console.log('B')
    super.foo();
  }
}

class C extends B {
  foo() {
    console.log('C')
    super.foo();
  }
}

// Somewhere else
class User {
  static bar() {
    C.instance().foo(); // Sometimes, this calls B.foo() directly, C.foo() is bypassed!
  }
}

// call B.instance first
console.log('B.foo')
B.instance().foo();

console.log('C.foo')
User.bar()
```

Comment: Why not even inherit the `instance` method, using `this` instead of the respective class name?

Comment: @Bergi Yep a better option would be to rewrite `instance` to use `this`.

Comment: Previously when I use ES5 I was doing the same thing, why didn't this happen? Was I just lucky? I had always thought `C._instance` and `B._instance` are separate namespaces. Afterall, it's `function C()` and `function B()`.

Comment: @huggie " I had always thought C._instance and B._instance are separate namespaces." They have one way "connection". C.[[prototype]] is set to be B. Everything you add to `B` later will be immediatelly available in `C` via prototype chain.